# Left Joins in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join, left-join

This question might seem quite trival, but being new to sql programming I'm having some trouble understanding the left joins.

To illustrate, I have the following scenario -

I have to perform left joins on the following tables -

```
from T1.id to T2.id
from T2.Oi to T3.Oi
from T1.Pi to T4.Pi
from t4.Si to T5.Si
from T6.Ki to T7.Ki
```

I'm trying to do the following method, but not sure if its correct approach, if so, then not sure if its an efficient approach

```
select /*(whatever I want)*/
from
T1 left join T2 on T1.id = T2.id
left join T4 on T1.Pi = T4.Pi
left join T5 on T4.Si = T5.Si
left join T3 on T2.Oi = T3.Oi
(Getting stuck on joining T6 and T7)
```

Can someone help me in understanding if my above approach is right and how solve in joining T6 and T7

Cheers!

Comment: But how is t6 related to any of the t1 - t5 tables?

Answer (score 0):

joining tables T1..T5 should be like that:

```
SELECT *
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2
ON T2.ID=T1.ID
LEFT JOIN T3
ON T3.OI=T2.OI
LEFT JOIN T4
ON T4.PI=T1.PI
LEFT JOIN T5
ON T5.SI=T4.SI
```

I don't know what you have in those tables so please consider cartesian product (of course it can be desired result in some cases). Read more [here](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Cartesian_join).

I don't know what about tables T6 and T7. If records are in the same form you may want to use UNION (please consider UNION ALL operator - [read about difference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm):

```
SELECT *
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2
ON T2.ID=T1.ID
LEFT JOIN T3
ON T3.OI=T2.OI
LEFT JOIN T4
ON T4.PI=T1.PI
LEFT JOIN T5
ON T5.SI=T4.SI
UNION
SELECT *
FROM T6
LEFT JOIN T7
ON T7.KI=T6.KI
```